# ClikcOnce deployment problem

Tags: clickonce

I am trying to test ClickOnce in my local PC. I set the necessary check boxes for updates and publish the project. First I publish the project to a local folder and then install. I diuble click the executable created from installation and it works fine.

Then I update the app code and do another publish. bit now when I double click the executable it does not ask for update, just load the old version.

Can someone tell me why this can be happening. I have checked the proper boxed when publishing I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Check the "Publish" tab in your project's properties.  Are you incrementing the version number when you publish?